# Why does VBScript return a different value for the %ProgramFiles% system variable in an HTA file vs in a VBS file?

Tags: vbscript, hta

On a 64 bit PC, the following code in a VBS file will return "C:\Program Files" as expected.

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles%")
```

However, when the same code is placed inside an HTA file, it returns "C:\Program Files (x86)".  The following is the HTA file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTA Test </title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
        ApplicationName = "Test App"
        ID      = "test"
        WindowState = "normal "
        SysMenu = "yes "
        Scroll      = "no"
        Version = "1.0" />
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
    Dim oShell
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MsgBox oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles%")
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

On the PC, the following 2 system variable exist.

```
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htafile\Shell\Open\Command (which is used to open hta files) will see the OS is by default calling the 32bit version of MSHTA.exe, so, for a 32bit file, %programfiles% returns the value of %programfiles(x86)%

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I figured it had to be something like that.